# Want to add show more to every <p> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-proxy

I used `parentElement.appendChild(SpanTag)` for every class but the span tag gets added  only to the last `<p>` tag.

```js
var divsToControl = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var spanTag = document.createElement('span');
spanTag.innerText = "...see more";

for (var i = 0; i < divsToControl.length; i++) {
  var count = divsToControl[i].innerHTML.length;
  if (count > 200) {
    divsToControl[i].innerHTML = divsToControl[i].innerHTML.substring(0, 300);
    divsToControl[i].appendChild(spanTag);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Cutting the Text</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis
  praesentium hic eum facere earum aliquid, quas, animi est vitae quidem molestiae corrupti ullam, laboriosam cupiditate neque beatae quod impedit. Lorem, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum corporis repudiandae quo doloribus.
  Eligendi ullam sunt minus hic, accusantium quae!
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis
  praesentium hic eum facere earum aliquid, quas, animi est vitae quidem molestiae corrupti ullam, laboriosam cupiditate neque beatae quod impedit. Lorem, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum corporis repudiandae quo doloribus.
  Eligendi ullam sunt minus hic, accusantium quae!
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis
  praesentium hic eum facere earum aliquid, quas, animi est vitae quidem molestiae corrupti ullam, laboriosam cupiditate neque beatae quod impedit. Lorem, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum corporis repudiandae quo doloribus.
  Eligendi ullam sunt minus hic, accusantium quae!
</p>
```

I get the output like below

```
Cutting the Text
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis praesentium hic eum facere earum a

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis praesentium hic eum facere earum a

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis praesentium hic eum facere earum a...see more
```

I want `...more applied` to every paragraph like below

```
Cutting the Text
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis praesentium hic eum facere earum a...see more

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis praesentium hic eum facere earum a...see more

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis praesentium hic eum facere earum a...see more
```

Comment: `divsToControl.appendChild(spanTag);` doesn’t make sense. `divsToControl` isn’t an Element. Did you mean `divsToControl[i]`? Also, for future reference: See [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Comment: `divsToControl.appendChild` should be `divsToControl[i].appendChild`

Comment: You use the same span element over and over. An element can only live in one place.      `divsToControl[i].appendChild(spanTag.cloneNode());`

Comment: You can not append the _same_ element into _multiple_ locations. `appendChild` will _remove_ a node from its current position, if it is already in the document, before it gets appended to the new one. You need to create a span element for each paragraph, resp. clone the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that you only created 1 `span` element, but you should create a new one for each paragraph:

```js
const divsToControl = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < divsToControl.length; i++) {
  const count = divsToControl[i].innerHTML.length;
  
  if (count > 200) {
    const spanTag = document.createElement('span');
    spanTag.innerText = "...see more";
    divsToControl[i].innerHTML = divsToControl[i].innerHTML.substring(0, 300);
    divsToControl[i].appendChild(spanTag);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Cutting the Text</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis
  praesentium hic eum facere earum aliquid, quas, animi est vitae quidem molestiae corrupti ullam, laboriosam cupiditate neque beatae quod impedit. Lorem, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum corporis repudiandae quo doloribus.
  Eligendi ullam sunt minus hic, accusantium quae!
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis
  praesentium hic eum facere earum aliquid, quas, animi est vitae quidem molestiae corrupti ullam, laboriosam cupiditate neque beatae quod impedit. Lorem, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum corporis repudiandae quo doloribus.
  Eligendi ullam sunt minus hic, accusantium quae!
</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia debitis beatae asperiores corrupti fugiat perferendis minima hic aliquid quibusdam et, molestiae tempore commodi amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A perspiciatis
  praesentium hic eum facere earum aliquid, quas, animi est vitae quidem molestiae corrupti ullam, laboriosam cupiditate neque beatae quod impedit. Lorem, Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum corporis repudiandae quo doloribus.
  Eligendi ullam sunt minus hic, accusantium quae!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`divsToControl.appendChild(spanTag);`

The problem here is that you are appending the one span element, so you append it, then move it to the next, then move it the next and so on. Eventually, you move it to the last element.

Instead, you need to create a new span for every paragraph, inside the loop.

Comment: thank you. i understood what was the mistake.